# How to implement Minimap of KineticJS Layer?

Tags: javascript, layer, kineticjs, stage

I am currently working on an application which displays kind of amap. You can do several actions on the map. The map can get really big so the user needs a smaller map (Minimap) to keep track of the whole map.

Currently there are two stages. The one for the big map, one for the minimap. The big map contains several layers, but only one of them needs to be displayed on the minimap (its like a layout).

So I thought about adding an EventListener for AfterDrawing of the specific layer.

`this.layoutLayer.afterDraw(this._initMinimap);`

In the Event Listener I am doing the following:

```
//...
_initMinimap : function(event) {
    var ctrl = event;
    if (!this.minimap) {
        this.minimap = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container : 'container',
            width : 165,
            height : 165
        });
    }
    if (!this.mapLayer) {
        this.mapLayer = new Kinetic.Layer({});
    }
    this.mapLayer.clear();
    this.minimap.clear();
    this.layoutLayer.toImage({
        callback : function(img) {
            var image = new Kinetic.Image({
                image : img
            });
            image.setScale(0.01,0.01);
            ctrl.mapLayer.add(image);
        }
    });
    this.minimap.add(this.mapLayer);
    this.minimap.draw();
},
//...
```

Does anyone has an idea of how to solve this issue? I am not that familiar with JavaScript yet so I am not quite sure if this is the right approach.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: While you explained what you want to achieve, you have not thoroughly explained the problem you are having. You just posted some code which creates a new stage, a new layer, makes an image out of a layoutLayout layer, then adds that image to the layer, and draws the stage. Can you describe the issue?

Comment: a simpler approach would be to just draw all the mini map layers, and hide them all immediately. Then when your event fires, show the layer you want.

Comment: Oh ya, you got a point there @EliteOctagon .

Okay I just look through my code and got another idea.
Isn't it possible to just assign the layoutLayer with a smaller scale to another stage? I tried to copy the reference of the layoutLayer to another variable, scale it down and add it to another stage. But as I said, I am just copying the reference and not "cloning" the layer.

Comment: Now the problem is that I don't have the layer on both stages. It automatically is deleted on the one stage when added to another.

Comment: well, you could clone it... stage2.add(layer1.clone());

Comment: If you need to 'move' layers just do layer.moveTo(stage2), maybe on mouse click? then on some other event move the layer from stage2 to stage1

Comment: if you need relative pointers, you could do stage2.getChildren() to get you a list of layers in stage2 and then do a for loop to move all children in that stage to stage1.

Comment: I am now using the layer.clone() Method. Since the LayoutLayer can get really big" I have developed a method which returns the dimension of the layoutLayer to scale the cloned Layout for the Minimap. Dimension in this case means, the greatest difference (X or Y) between all Childs.
Now I am implementing a rectangle which lays on this minimap. This rectangle can be moved; according to its drag&drop the big map is moved. I hope you get my picture here.
Thanks for helping out so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can get a miniature copy of the layer by using `clone` and `scale`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Minimap Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container"></div>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/kineticjs/5.0.6/kinetic.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var squareQuantity = 10,
                tileWidth = window.innerWidth / squareQuantity,
                tileHeight = window.innerHeight / squareQuantity,
                background = new Kinetic.Layer,
                stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight,
                    container: 'container'
                });

            for ( var x = 0; x < squareQuantity; x++ ){
                for ( var y = 0; y < squareQuantity; y++ ){
                    background.add(
                        new Kinetic.Rect({
                            x: x * tileWidth,
                            y: y * tileHeight,
                            width: tileWidth,
                            height: tileHeight,
                            fill: '#' + Math.random().toString( 16 ).substring( 2, 8 )
                        })
                    )
                }
            }

            var mini = background.clone().scale({ x: 0.2, y: 0.2 });

            stage.add( background );
            stage.add( mini );

            background.draw();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pCjlb)